# Drop-down menu is not working for some reason

Tags: html, css

My dropdown effect is not working what am I doing wrong. I have tried by putting display to `none` and using the `:hover` but nothing works.

As soon as I hover over the Menu, `.drp-btn:hover .menu-content-container` doesn't work.

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="drp-btn"> Menu </div>
    
    <div class="menu-content-container">
        <ul class="menu-content">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Booking</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.nav-container {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-content-container {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.drp-btn {
    margin-left: 60vw;
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.drp-btn:hover .menu-content-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.menu-content-container {
    display: none;
}

.nav-container ul li {
    margin-left: 2%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-container a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="drp-btn"> Menu 
        <div class="menu-content-container">
            <ul class="menu-content">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

wrap  the code drp-btn div

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your menu-content-container into the drp-btn div to make that work:

```css
.nav-container {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-content-container {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.drp-btn {
    margin-left: 60vw;
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.drp-btn:hover .menu-content-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.menu-content-container {
    display: none;
}

.nav-container ul li {
    margin-left: 2%;
    list-style-type: none;

}

.nav-container a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
                <div class="drp-btn"> Menu 
                  <div class="menu-content-container">
                    <ul class="menu-content">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Booking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
  </div>

                
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't that work separately? why do I need to wrap that inside drp-btn?